# Standalone python app that uses qgis.core without installing qgis

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am building a standalone python application that has its own GUI, i would like to use qgis.core/pyqgis as a map display only. But from my searches on this topic, it seems that the full QGis software has to be installed on both developer and prospective users' machine to have this work. Is there not a way to embed Qgis map display **without installing** the full version of Qgis software?

Comment: What is the OS you would install your standalone application on?

Comment: I'm extremely new to QGIS, but I'm assigned to develop a custom application with maps. I've understood that pyQgis is the savior. But installing QGIS is not possible. Could you please elaborate whether the above approach is promising? BDW I'm sorry I can't comment on the above answer.
Thank you for the time.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/81776)

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge, it's possible although I didn't investigate.

This answer is due to [IntraMaps Roam](https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam), a field data collection application built using the QGIS libraries and Python.

Quoting the description

> IntraMaps Roam is built as a standalone fully packaged Python
>   application with everything included. QGIS is **not** required to be
>   installed on the client machine and only on the machine that builds
>   Roam from source.

Comment: thanks, this looks promising, I would like to investigate further on that project, which could take a bit time. If no one else gives other thoughts, then I'll accept this as an answer in a few days. Thanks.