# Writing custom GUI map application without installing QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, standalone

I would like to know if it is possible to develop standalone map applications with QGIS without installing QGIS software or embedding QGIS. Most instructions ask to either install QGIS or embed in to the final executable.
Is it possible to call QGIS functionalities by using shared libs? According to this ([Standalone python app that uses qgis.core without installing qgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175726/standalone-python-app-that-uses-qgis-core-without-installing-qgis/187130#187130)) answer there's one example application, https://github.com/DMS-Aus/Roam which requires py2exe to be installed.

Is there a promising way to achieve the objective without installing QGIS?

Comment: Installed on the dev machine or on the user of the applications machine?

Comment: @Nathan, without installing the QGIS application on client mahine. And, the solution need not support multi platform. Just windows is enough.

Comment: py2exe is what you want. It will create an exe and build everything together.

Comment: Just to complete this discussion, I started using the geotools library with java swing application and it serves the purpose. I can load maps with current shape files.